# How to use -I option in Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

### Edit:

I now know how to compile using @MadScientist answer to add

```
VPATH = include
```

to the makefile.

But I though that the -I option is enough for that.

I mean, if my makefile has line

```
g++ $(CFLAGS) -I./include -c reciprocal.cpp
```

I think it is enough to find the file reciprocal.h that I need.

It is not clear to me why should I have in makefile the -I option for the gcc & also a line VPATH that tells where to look for ? -I should be enough?

### Origin quest

Trying to compile simple files (according advanced linux programming) using makefile.

My problem is the -I option (include path).

My files structure is simple:

Working directory is exam.
(If all files (reciprocal.cpp & reciprocal.h) are under exam directory all compiled fine!)

under exam I have:
1 directory named include which have inside reciprocal.h.
3 files named main.c reciprocal.cpp & Makefile
like:

```
/exam/
     include/
            reciprocal.h
     main.c
     reciprocal.cpp
     Makefile
```

Now, 
reciprocal.h code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern double reciprocal (int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

main.c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "reciprocal.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    i = atoi (argv[1]);
    printf ("The reciprocal of %d is %g\n", i, reciprocal (i));
    return 0;
}
```

reciprocal.cpp code

```
#include <cassert>
#include "reciprocal.h"

double reciprocal (int i) {
    // I should be non-zero.
#ifdef NDEBUG
    assert (i != 0);
    use macro NDEBUG
#endif // NDEBUG
    return 1.0/i;
}
```

Makefile :

```
reciprocal: main.o reciprocal.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal main.o reciprocal.o
main.o: main.c reciprocal.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -I./include -c main.c 
reciprocal.o: reciprocal.cpp reciprocal.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -I./include -c reciprocal.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o reciprocal
```

I get an error : 
make: *** No rule to make target `reciprocal.h', needed by`main.o'.  Stop.
and I can not get what it is...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We used to create three folders in project folder:

1. headers (inc/)
2. source files (src/)
3. object files (obj/)

Thus the Makefile would look like:

```
obj:
    mkdir obj

reciprocal: obj/main.o inc/reciprocal.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal obj/main.o obj/reciprocal.o

obj/main.o: src/main.c inc/reciprocal.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS)  -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o

obj/reciprocal.o: src/reciprocal.cpp inc/reciprocal.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c src/reciprocal.cpp -o obj/reciprocal.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o reciprocal
```

It is much simpler and I find it used by the majority of programmers in Poland.

Answer (score 0):

The `-I` option passed to the compiler will tell the *compiler* where to find the header file.  It doesn't tell *make* where to find anything: make has no idea that you've passed that flag to the compiler.

And it's make that is printing that error, because it can't find one of your prerequisites.

This is a good opportunity to use [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html); just add:

```
VPATH = include
```

to your makefile, now make will look there for prerequisites and be able to find them.

Comment: I tried to add this line and now I get compilation error <br/> gcc  -c main.c 
main.c:2:24: fatal error: reciprocal.h: No such file or directory
 #include "reciprocal.h" <br/>

Comment: That's a different problem.  The command line you show in your comment above `gcc -c main.c` bears no relationship to the makefile you posted here, so either you miscopied it into your comment or your makefile is different than the one above.  Either way, this is a different problem.  You should either create a new question or at least edit your question with the new information with proper formatting, cut/paste of commands and errors, etc. rather than adding it into comments.